# mock place_changed event event from google places API

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-testing-library

I have added the place autocomplete feature to an input in my React project.

```
const onPlaceChange = () => {
    let address = autoCompleteService.current.getPlace();
    onAddressChange(address);
}

autoCompleteService.current = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById(id), options);

autoCompleteService.current.addListener("place_changed", onPlaceChange);
```

I'm trying to write a unittest with react-testing-library but I can't get the place_changed event to fire. I've tried

```
fireEvent(addressInput, createEvent('place_changed', addressInput, {target: {value: "123 fake st."}}))
```

Where addressInput is the input DOM element, but that doesn't seem to work. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you make any progress with this?

Comment: @Jacob Pecile could find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

`fireEvent` won't work because that event is a part of a custom event on the Autocomplete class which extends `google.maps.MVCObject`.

Basically `addListener !== addEventListener`.

I have a partial set of mocks for Google Maps at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/jest-mocks. Looks like the [MVCObject.trigger](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/event#event.trigger) is missing from the mock library though. That might get you closer though.

Comment: has there been a progress with adding ` MVCObject.trigger ` to the mock library?